# Python 'corrupts' downloaded pdf file

Tags: python, encoding, python-requests, urllib, wikipedia

I am writing a program to automatically download a Wikipedia page as pdf, using their embedded tool.

I was able to fix a problem where I wasn't able to retrieve the data from a submit button. The new problem is, that I can download the file (I used `open()` and also `urllib.request.urlretrieve()`, but I'm not able to open it manually then. 
It seems like the file is being corrupted while being downloaded (I think it's an encoding failure). This disables opening the PDF.. (unsupported datatype or corrupted file=

This is the code I use:

```
import requests
import urllib.request

base_url = 'https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/'
def createURL(base):
    title = 'Rektifikation (Verfahrenstechnik)'
    name = title.replace(" ", "_")
    url = (base + name).replace('(', '%28').replace(')', '%29')
    print(url)
    getPDF(url, title)

def getPDF(url, title):
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
    open('{}.pdf'.format(title), 'wb').write(r.content)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Spezial:ElectronPdf&page=Rektifikation+%28Verfahrenstechnik%29&action=show-download-screen)', '{}_vl.pdf'.format(title))

createURL(base_url)
```

I hardcoded most of the stuff for debugging reasons. Feel free to help me improve the code, but note that this isn't my main purpose, please.

My question now is: What could I possibly do to stop the file from getting corrupted (encode it the right way)

[This](https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Spezial:ElectronPdf&page=Rektifikation%20%28Verfahrenstechnik%29&action=show-download-screen) is the link (click the button) I'm trying to download from.
Note: It's an instant download link with a redirect.

Thanks for your help, if you need any more information just ask me.

EDIT: Opening the PDF via Word lets me see, that the data (texts, paragraphs..) is available. So the PDF contains the data and the download itself seems to be successful.

The sizes of the downloaded files differ, maybe someone can have a look at this problem too:
open: 58KB
urllib: 18KB
manually: 239KB

Comment: I see you call `open` for writing, but do you ever close the stream? Personally I try to always do `with open(...) as f:` instead of just open. What happens if you call `open` with `'w'` instead of `'wb'`?

Comment: Sure, usually I do this too, my bad.
Using `'w'`: TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes.

I tried `.decode('utf-8')` then, which lead to another error during the decoding..

Comment: If you open dev tools in your browser, and view the requests made to retrieve the pdf by clicking the button you can see the actual url is `https://de.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/pdf/Rektifikation_(Verfahrenstechnik`.  Fetching this url using requests works.